# angularjs can't show file from api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, symfony

I have an app where frontend is developed in angularjs and backend with symfony.

I need to have a route like: http://example.com/api/invoices/file?file=foo

So I have this inside my FileController:

```
/**
     * Matches /invoices/file/{filename} exactly
     *
     * @Route("/invoices/file/{filename}", name="get_invoice_file")
     */
    public function getInvoiceFileAction(string $filename, Request $request)
    {
        $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/invoices/' . $filename;

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            return new Response('file not found', 404);
        }

        $file = file_get_contents($path);
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Conteng-Length' => filesize($path)
        ];

        return new Response($file, 200, $headers);
    }
```

Inside my angularjs app I have this to get the response inside my frontend controller:

```
vm.getInvoices = function() {
            vm.loading = true;
            apiResolver.resolve('invoices.documents.file@get', { "file": vm.searchFile }).then(function(response) {
                vm.loading = false;

                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                vm.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

            }); 
        };
```

Into my html I have this:

```
<embed ng-src="{{vm.file}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></embed>
```

When I render the page I see a 200response so the file exist but into the html I have an empty space instead of pdf file.
Inside embed tag there is this:

```
<embed style="width:200px;height:200px;" ng-src="blob:http://localhost:3000/d32d87d1-6582-42e3-85ae-dc174ca5a473" src="blob:http://localhost:3000/d32d87d1-6582-42e3-85ae-dc174ca5a473">
```

If I copy url inside a browser returns me that can't load file.

Backend and frontend are in different folder and the pdf CAN'T be viewed by a public link infact these pages are protected with jwt system.

How can I show inside my page the pdf?
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that JWT **Authorization Token** is passed in the request . If not , pass it in the Blob object.

If token is passed try replacing `embed` to `object` as mentioned below :

```
<object data="{{vm.file}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Comment: I guess token is not required if file is already downloaded by Front-end . Let me know if above answere works for you